# If/And/Match Formula only returning first result - need for entire range

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I've scoured the site and can't find the answer I need for this problem.

I'm trying to create a formula that checks whether a particular text string is present in a range, but also if the cell adjacent to that text string match is a Y or N (for whether approved,yes or no). If that text string is found, but the corresponding rating is a N, that's the same as it not being there at all for me, so it would result in a "NO".

This is what I have right now:

```
=IF(AND(MATCH(B2,RngF,0)>0,INDEX(RngG,MATCH(B2,RngF,0))="Y"),"YES","NO")
```

`B2` contains the relevant text

`RngF` is the column with many rows of text, included that in `B2`.

`RngG` contains `Y` or `N` for each item in `RngF`.

Right now this formula works, except for one problem. If the text in `B2` is found in `RngF` and there is a corresponding `Y` in `RngG`, it only returns the first instance of this. So if the first row has `B2` and a `N`, but the second row has `B2` and a `Y`, it will still give me a "No" because the first thing it found was the `N`. I need it to look past this and tell me if it finds any instances of `B2` with a `Y`, not just the first.

Does it maybe have to do with my exact match selection (the -1,0,1)?

Also, if there is an alternative way you think this could be done, a different type of formula altogether, I am welcome to that feedback as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your lookup ranges are in columns A and B, and your lookup value is in `D1`, this should work:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,"Y")>0,"Found","Not found")
```